# nearby locations with appropriate zoom level

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I have a mysql database with 13.000 locations. With html geolocation I find the users' location by defining a radius (e.g. 1 km) I calculate a bounding box and use that to find (sql) locations within that radius. Input: geolocation user, Output: (sorted) array of locations within 1 km radius.

This doesn't work if there are no locations within that radius. What I want is to show approximately 10 locations nearby, regardless of radius. This means google map zoom level should be dynamic and also the sql search should be done different. Input: geolocation user, Output: 10 locations nearby, no radius predefined and locations should be more or less visible on the map -> appropriate map zoom level.

I was thinking of starting of with 1 km, and if there is no location in that range, increasing the radius with +100 meters and keeping looping till +/- 10 locations are found (sort and put them in an array). Then find the distance from user's location and last location in array (largest distance) and from there on calculate the appropriate google map zoom level.

I have one problem: what if the nearest location is within 20 km? With an increment of 100 m in each loop it will loop through this calculation 200 times! I am afraid this will result in long waiting times.

How should I solve this issue? Is there another way to get nearby locations?

This is my mysql table structure (where formid represents the ID of a location), total of 189.031 rows.

[image]

EDIT: I have tried the answer of Ollie jones and this is the script I use (I divide the counter by 2 because I have language duplicates of each address):

```
 $rad = 0.2;  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

 $R = 6371;  // earths mean radius, km

  // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
  $maxLat = $_GET['lat'] + rad2deg($rad/$R);
  $minLat = $_GET['lat'] - rad2deg($rad/$R);
  // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
  $maxLon = $_GET['long'] + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($_GET['lat'])));
  $minLon = $_GET['long'] - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($_GET['lat'])));

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; ; $i++) {

  // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
  $maxLat = $_GET['lat'] + rad2deg($rad/$R);
  $minLat = $_GET['lat'] - rad2deg($rad/$R);
  // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
  $maxLon = $_GET['long'] + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($_GET['lat'])));
  $minLon = $_GET['long'] - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($_GET['lat'])));

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE content BETWEEN '".$minLat."' AND '".$maxLat."'";

$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);  

$counter = 0;
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = 'LON' AND formid = {$row3["formid"]} AND content BETWEEN '".$minLon."' AND '".$maxLon."'";

$result4 = mysqli_query($link, $sql3);  

while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
    $counter = $counter + 1;; // or $counter = $counter + 1;
}
}
$total = $counter/2;
echo $total;    
if ($total >= 2 || $rad >= 30) {
$end = microtime(true);
$time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);
echo 'This page loaded in ', $time, ' seconds';
break;  

}
$rad = $rad * sqrt(2);
}
/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** After the OQ posted some code, I posted another answer to this question.  Please see it. It's more to the point than this answer.

Your basic idea seems OK: that is, increase the search radius if you don't get enough points within your first try.

You suggest increasing the search radius by 100m each time you try. That seems a very non-aggressive search-range-widening strategy.

Instead, why not boost the radius by 41.4% (radius * sqrt(2)) of the current radius each time? That way you'll double the geographic area searched with each iteration. Your query already returns the nearest ten points, so you won't get insane results back even if you suddenly pull in a thousand points in one of your iterations.

Notice that if your 13,000 points are postcode/zip code centroids, 1km is not a very good starting point for this search. It's unlikely you'll find ten within any particular 1km radius except in dense urban areas. You may want to start larger.

**Edit** Thanks for updating your question to include information about the structure of your table and your queries. That helps a lot.

You present a difficult optimization problem. Your latitude and longitude values are stored in an attribute table. Presumably they are stored as text "-45.12345" rather than FLOAT values. Optimizing these geoqueries *requires* the use of a sequentially scannable index on, at a minimum, the latitude values.  That is, you need to be able to say something like this in SQL.

```
SELECT whatever FROM sometable 
 WHERE attribute = 'LAT'
   AND content BETWEEN ?lat-radius AND ?lat+radius
```

(`?lat` is the latitude of your candidate point.) The server needs to be able to fulfill that request by random-accessing an index starting at `?-radius` and then scanning sequentially to `?+radius`.  The server can't do that: your query contains an implicit typecast from text to FLOAT like this. The typecast defeats indexing.

```
SELECT whatever FROM sometable
 WHERE attribute = 'LAT'
   AND CAST(content AS FLOAT) BETWEEN ?lat-radius AND ?lat+radius
```

So, unless you change your schema so LAT and LONG can be FLOAT values with indexes this query is going to be slow independent of the `radius` searched. A small `radius` won't help and a large `radius` won't hurt.

SO: the easiest way to improve performance is to do the query once. The iterative expansion of the radius I first suggested is pointless with your table structure. Use a large radius (50km), and take the nearest points to the candidate point using `ORDER BY dist ASC LIMIT n`.

There's another class of solution to this problem. It involve creating a shadow lat/long table using some kind of trigger or other update methodology. But that's a lot of work, and you may not be up for it.

FYI, here's a writeup on solving the geolocation problem.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Comment: I like the idea of not just randomly increasing with 100 m but doubling the search area. 

About your remark of 1 km range: it is indeed this problem. The locations are mainly stores/shops in an urban area (and 1 km shows maybe 30 locations on a map?) but if you are living in a small village you almost won't see any location because google map zoom level is not appropriate.

Comment: I have just tried this method, however this is maybe a little bit too "aggressive". For example, when iterating the first 11 loops it finds 0 hits (6.5 km) and in the 12th loop, 9.05 km, it gives 148 locations. Total execution time of 9 seconds!

Comment: I have changed the radius to 50 km and my result: 0.77 seconds! If I start at 0,2 km, iterating with an increment of * sqrt(2) it takes 8.90 seconds! I was sceptical towards beginning with a large radius because I thought it would take a very long time, but it turns out that iterating is even more timeconsuming. I tried the script within a densed area (> 2000 locations) and in an small town (9 locations), each calculation takes up to approximately 0.7 seconds which is good enough for me. I don't really understand how you suggest to order the results. I thought adding to an array and sort?

Comment: The trick is to get the MySQL server to do it. In the light of your posted code I am going to write another answer.

Comment: Ollie Jones, I cannot find your other answer back or the chat!

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be not to show a location when in 20km radius there isn't any. Another solution is to compute the voronoi diagram. Then you can use the diagram to filter nearby cities. You can read about an example here:http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/nearest-neighbours-voronoi-diagrams-and-finding-your-nearest-sql-server-usergroup/.

Comment: Should a voronoi diagram be calculated beforehand or everytime a user initiates a location lookup? I can imagine it will take a while to calculate such a diagram.

Comment: You need it to compute it only if you add a city or delete a city... For faster query you can use point in location problem.

Comment: The problem here lies that locations are added regularly by visitors of the site. The site has a high amount of visitors and I think making this diagram would not be suitable in this situation.

Comment: It isn't about locations.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer was given before the schema and code was added to question. I will leave it as it may help others in future.

The following SQL query uses [**Spherical Law of Cosines**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate the distance between a coordinate and coordinates in a table. It limits result to 10 and orders by distance.

> d = acos( sin(lat1).sin(lat2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).cos(lng2-lng1) ).R

```
SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($center_lat) ) 
                        * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng )
                        - radians($center_lng) ) + sin( radians($center_lat) ) 
                        * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table 
                        ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Where `$center_lat` & `$center_lng` are coordinates of location.

The query uses [**SQL Math functions**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx)

Query took 0.2506 sec on database with 50,068 rows

Comment: Wow that is fast. However, my table structure is a messed up due to a 3rd party plugin. I don't have a table where each row represents a location with a column "lat" and "lng". I have a table with rows, each containing one value. So location 1 has +/- 20 rows (row 1: name, row 2: lat, row 3: lng etc.). Total of 189,031 rows. Columns: ID, formid, fieldid, attritube, content. 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE content BETWEEN '".$minLat."' AND '".$maxLat."'";

if this yields results: 

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = 'LON' AND content BETWEEN '".$minLon."' AND '".$maxLon."'";

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the mysql table in the first post.

Comment: For what it's worth, this query necessarily must scan the full `table` to get its results. Winnowing by bounding box, even just on latitude, will help performance a lot. You may not need performance helped in this specific case, but other queries will.

Comment: @Ollie Jones, I have just added the iteration script including your suggestion of multiplying the radius with sqrt(2). I think the difficult issue here is that the locations are mostly shops in a city centre, which means that if you are living in a smaller town or you are on the high way it takes a long time to calculate.

Comment: @OllieJones Of course a bounding box could help but unless bounding box contains at least 10 coordinates we would still be left with initial  problem.